# how to use Replaykit to record screen in background of outside the app

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I followed some tutorials to implement a screen recorder with `Replaykit`. for example this one https://www.appcoda.com/replaykit/ .

it works fine and no special problem exists. but the main problem is that it does not record in background. I mean when I leave the app while still recording and touch Home button then recording will be stopped untill I open the app again. I wonder to know is it possible to record background with the help of `Replaykit`? if so please give me some brief explanaition how to do it. Thank you. I appreciate any kinds of help

Comment: No that is not possible !!

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya is it possible to suggest me a way to do it?

Comment: neda sorry to say but there are no public API Available to record even when app closed  :(

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Thank you very much. how about broadcast extension? do you think I can do it by my self coding? is it possible in device I mean? because I have seen some apps like this

Comment: I am afraid that your app might be rejected if you are trying to access something out of the context of your app.    you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36382991/4601900   If you think broadcast extension will work then you should give a try then

Comment: Thank you very much for your great information. but as there is many apps in the app store which it records whole device and I need some function in my app same to this to check some exams, then I need to find a way to implement this. Thank you very much. I will check the link . Appreciate your time @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: Good luck with that , and when you find something you can answer your own question here that might helpful to other people facing the same issue :)

Comment: Not true. Replaykit 2 allows recording of the entire iOS screen, even in background. Tutorials rare

Comment: @decades can you help me or introduce any tutorial please? or even a guide to do that. please . Appreciate

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/anthonya1999/ReplayKit-iOS11-Recorder/blob/master/ReplayKit-iOS11-Recorder/ViewController.m